# React Hook useEffect has some missing dependencies

Tags: react-hooks

I tried to run a program, but I got this warning message: Line 75:8:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'client' and 'loading'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

This is my Code

```js
const UserList = ({ setSelectedUsers }) => {
    const { client } = useChatContext();
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [listEmpty, setListEmpty] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const getUsers = async () => {
            if(loading) return;

            setLoading(true);
            
            try {
                const response = await client.queryUsers(
                    { id: { $ne: client.userID } },
                    { id: 1 },
                    { limit: 8 } 
                );

                if(response.users.length) {
                    setUsers(response.users);
                } else {
                    setListEmpty(true);
                }
            } catch (error) {
               setError(true);
            }
            setLoading(false);
        }

        if(client) getUsers()
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the warning by // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps above the useEffect dependency. useEffect sometimes suggests useless dependencies that should not be actually added in dependency array

````
useEffect(() => {
        const getUsers = async () => {
            if(loading) return;

            setLoading(true);
            
            try {
                const response = await client.queryUsers(
                    { id: { $ne: client.userID } },
                    { id: 1 },
                    { limit: 8 } 
                );

                if(response.users.length) {
                    setUsers(response.users);
                } else {
                    setListEmpty(true);
                }
            } catch (error) {
               setError(true);
            }
            setLoading(false);
        }

        if(client) getUsers()
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);```
````

Comment: please mark my answer correct if it helped :)